# How to Retrieve iOS Bundle ID and Android Package Name for Registering React Native Expo App with Firebase JS SDK?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I've been struggling to find a solution for obtaining the iOS Bundle ID and Android Package Name to register my React Native Expo app on Firebase using the Firebase JavaScript SDK. I've searched extensively, but haven't been able to find a clear answer.

Do I need to switch to React Native Firebase instead of using the Firebase JavaScript SDK?

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance on this matter. Thank you in advance.

This is my `app.json`:

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "testingfirebase",
    "slug": "testingfirebase",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to interact with Firebase SDK  with Expo.

**1. Firebase JavaScript SDK (Designed for the web)**

Firebase treats your app as a web app and you don't need to configure either ios or Android package ID.

Firebase JS  SDK has limited features - Cloud Messaging/Notification, and Crashlytic are not supported.

Docs - https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#using-firebase-js-sdk

**2. Use [React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/)**

This package uses the corresponding Native SDKs for both Android and ios. This requires a package ID for each platform.

Docs - https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#install-and-initialize-react-native-firebase

Comment: So this means there's no way to get iOS or Android ID with Firebase JS SDK to register the app on Firebase?

Comment: You don't need to register app with package ID as app now considered as website.

Comment: Wow, this makes sense! Thank you so much! Please correct me if I'm wrong: This means that when using the Firebase JavaScript SDK, we register it as a web app on Firebase instead of an iOS or Android app. We then use this Firebase JavaScript SDK web app to submit to the Apple Store and Google Play Store later?

Comment: No. Firebase needs a package ID to identify the app only. Features like a Push notification or Crashlytics require that package ID to work and are unavailable for JavaScript SDK. You can publish the app to Apple Or Google Store even if you use Firebase JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Cool. Glad it was helpful.

Comment: how did you get bundle identifier for ios  ?  @Tui .